# Pokemon spawn for nearby players but not me

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been hanging out with my friends catching Pokémon, but whenever they catch lots of Pokémon, none spawn for me. Last night I sat for three hours in the middle of three increased stops, all my friends got a lot of Pokémon, and I only got a single one! I tried moving around, deleting and installing the app again, turning my phone on and off, but nothing works. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8):

From personal experience:

- If they have an incense up, the pokemon created by the incense will only appear for them (they are marked by the same purple thing circling around a player with incense)
- Even with different levels, all pokemon should spawn for everybody (except what has been explained at point 1). Their CP will different if you have a different trainer level though.
- If they see a pokemon you don't see, try moving closer to where it spawned for them. Sometimes they are just out of your range, and the small difference in GPS placement makes them see it, but not you.

Source: Plays with GF a lot. Sometimes we don't see the same pokemon, but when I walk 10 meters towards where it was on her map I can get it.

EDIT: To help with that, compare with your friends where the App sees you. It often happens that me and my GF are right next to each other, but in the app we are detected 50-100 meters apart.

LATE EDIT: It's been years, but something could also trigger you to not see some pokemon that others see. At some speed (idk what exactly) no pokemon will appear on your map. The speed is slow enough that being on a bus might trigger that, but barely. At the next long stop (like a red light) they should appear after a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The following is all from the internet, maybe from *Reddit*, but though I don't remember where I read it.

So I read that having set your displayed time on the phone *manually* might cause the issue of not seeing the same Pokémon as your friends although you're at the very same time at the very same spot.

The approach to solve this problem, implying it's caused by what I stated above, is to set your cellphone's time to update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your cellphone to automatically adjust the time and month, etc.

Comment: This will most likely not work. Also, you haven't really provided any information to back this up.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. it can work. I know it has helped several people.

Comment: Its Works to my friend. He have the same problem .. and when he turn the Automatic adjust of time on he's celphone, pokemon appears.

Comment: This same answer has been given 12 days ago by GrizZ. I recommend deleting this answer, because it does not add anything new.

Answer (score -1):

If they are at a higher level than you, you may not catch the same Pokémon.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, or provide a source?  It doesn't match my experiences at all.